# OIDC AspNetCore OpenIdConnectHandler Correlation Failed state property not found

Tags: single-sign-on, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have an OIDC authentication server based on Identity Server 4 which allows federation on to an external identity provider.

```
                services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddOpenIdConnect(extIDP.AuthScheme, extIDP.AuthDisplay, options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = extIDP.Options.SignInScheme;
                    options.SignOutScheme = extIDP.Options.SignOutScheme;
                    options.Authority = extIDP.Options.Authority;
                    options.ClientId = extIDP.Options.ClientId;
                    options.ClientSecret = extIDP.Options.ClientSecret;
                    options.ResponseType = extIDP.Options.ResponseType;
                    options.CallbackPath = extIDP.Options.CallbackPath;
                    options.SignedOutCallbackPath = extIDP.Options.SignedOutCallbackPath;
                    options.RemoteSignOutPath = extIDP.Options.RemoteSignOutPath;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = extIDP.Options.RequireHttpsMetadata;
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.Scope.Clear();
                    options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId);
                    options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile);
                    options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email);
                    options.Scope.Add(JwtClaimTypes.Role);
                });
```

Where extIDP comes from some configuration.
So this works just fine, but we have a client with an IDP that doesnt support a response mode of form_post (which is the default used in the setup above), so if I add in an extra line to the config to set the ResponseMode to "fragment" then we should be fine but it does not work.

I end up with a Correlation Error being reported
With verbose logging enabled in our Auth Server we get

> Warning: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler
>   ".AspNetCore.Correlation." state property not found

Note this is occurring when running against two test auth servers locally so has nothing to do with load balancing problems.
I also added a cookie policy to ensure it wasnt being cause by a strict cookie policy. So I am currently a bit stuck.

Comment: Actually thinking about it - is "fragment" response mode ever going to work?
The url fragment containing the id token is never going to be sent by the browser in the redirect request is it so the reported error is right there wont be any state info either. The only way it can work is if there is some javascript in the browser that extracts the fragment info and posts it to the server instead

Comment: Consider reading this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707345/oauth2-query-string-vs-fragment for clarification and play with ResponseType. You are right, that must work with a single page app and impicit flow.

Comment: Thanks - I think I am coming to the conclusion that only form_post makes sense in this federated gateway scenario

Comment: I recently blogged about the state and nonce parameter here:
* Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core - https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/